# How to get List of item using join in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working on an existing solution. Where I have two entities like

```
  public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
        private List<long> _accounts = new List<long>();

        [Display(Name = "Account No")]
        public List<long> Accounts
        {
            get { return _accounts; }
            set { _accounts = value; }
        }
        [Display(Name = "Account No")]
        public string AccountId
        {
            get { return string.Join(",", _accounts); }
            set { _accounts = value != null ? value.Split(',').Where(s=>!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Select(s => Convert.ToInt64(s.Trim())).ToList() : new List<long>(); }
        }

    }

     public class Account
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string AccountName { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }

    }
```

and also have one `ViewModel`

```
  public class UserAccountViewModel
    {
        public long AccountId { get; set; }
        public string AccountNo { get; set; }            
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }

    }
```

Now, how can I get `List<UserAccountViewModel>` from those entities?

Comment: You can't.  You need to have a mapping between the AccountId and the UserId.  You could have 5 users and 10 accounts and you do not know which user own each account.

Comment: A couple of questions. Why don't you map Account entity to User entity? Secondly, if an user can have multiple accounts, why UserAccountViewModel doesn't contain a list of accounts?

Comment: You need to have relationship between `Account` entity and `User` entity there - it seems require `ICollection` to have mapping between them. Also, it may require `List<Account> Accounts` in `UserAccountViewModel` to hold number of accounts.

Comment: I need  user list by account. And i can't do this. because i am working on an existing solution.

Comment: You seem to misuse singular and plural, which is confusing and not helping the readability of both the example and your codebase in general. `_account` (singular) is a list (multiple objects); and `AccountIds` (plural) returns a string (singular).

Comment: @Flater i update my question. Is it Ok now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I get my answer.It's something like below example:

```
        var users = new List<User>{
        new User{Id=1 ,Name="Test1",Email="test1@ds.com",DOB=DateTime.Now,AccountId ="1"},
        new User{Id=2 ,Name="Test2",Email="test2@ds.com",DOB=DateTime.Now,AccountId ="2"},
        new User{Id=3 ,Name="Test3",Email="test3@ds.com",DOB=DateTime.Now,AccountId ="3,4"}
        };
        var accunts = new List<Account>
        {
            new Account {Id=1,AccountName = "A",AccountNo = "1"},
            new Account {Id=2,AccountName = "B",AccountNo = "2"},
            new Account {Id=3,AccountName = "C",AccountNo = "3"},
            new Account {Id=4,AccountName = "D",AccountNo = "4"},
        };

        var userAccounts = (from u in users
                   from a in accunts
                   where u.Accounts.Contains(a.Id)
                   select new UserAccountViewModel
                   {
                       AccountNo = a.AccountNo,
                       AccountId = a.Id,
                       UserId = u.Id,
                       UserName = u.Name
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var UserAccountViewModel = (from Account in list1
             join UserAccountViewModel in list2
             on Account .AccountNo equals UserAccountViewModel.AccountNo 
             select new { UserAccountViewModel }).ToList();
```

Hope it helps you.
Or to increase the performance as per suggestion

```
var query = dataContext.UserAccountViewModel 
            .Include(o => o.Account)
            .Where(t=> t.AccountNo  == t.Account.AccountNo).ToList();
```

Comment: Using navigation properties is preferable over joins when using entity framwork. It's better optimized and better to understand.

Comment: This is not the answer. Please Read and understand my question first. I need exactly what i ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two lists of accnouts and users from which you want to create List, you can use:

```
var userAccount = (from account in list1
         join user in list2
         on account.Id.ToString() equals user.AccountIds
         select new UserAccountViewModel 
        { 
         AccountId = account.Id,
         AccountNo = account.AccountNo,
         UserName = user.Name,
         UserId = user.Id
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: You are in BD? seems like I could have come to your office and helped you. :)

Comment: This is not the answer. Please Read and understand my question first. I need exactly what i ask.Find my company name from my profile and you always welcome.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the question a bit more please to help us understand the question first.